# What Happens When an Assassin Shrouds a Target?

Tags: dnd-4e, assassin

Currently I have a player who has made an assassin. As many assassins do, he loves to hide around in the shadows, and pop out on an unsuspecting enemy and do as much damage as possible before dissolving away again. His preferred method of doing this is to place down a stack of assassin's shrouds on an enemy. However, while looking through feats we noticed one called *Hidden Insight* which had the effect of creatures not noticing shrouds when the assassin is hidden from them. I didn't see any mention in the rules about what enemies know when they are shrouded.

So, what exactly happens when an assassin places a shroud on an enemy? Do they know they are shrouded and thus more susceptible to damage? Do they know that an assassin placed it? Do they know where the assassin was when he placed it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a target knows the relevant facts about a power applied to it unless something says otherwise.

> A conscious creature affected by a power knows what a power has done to it, regardless of the power's type. [Rules Compendium 90]

This is because D&D 4e is a tactical combat engine and its focus is on making difficult tactical choices. Part of that involves being informed about the implication of one's choices; otherwise it'd be about making bad choices you don't know are tactical.

The Hidden Insight feat does allows you to break this rule a little bit. Your players strategy is viable with this feat. An assassin's shroud is *not* an attack so it can be placed without breaking hidden.

Comment: You should mention the Hidden Insight feat.

Comment: @András Please edit your insights on the feat into my answer; I don't have access to Dragon Magazine 379 so I can't look it up. It'd be a great addition to the answer, but Hidden Insight is not specific to the question itself (only to the context of the question), so I felt justified in providing an answer without that information.

Comment: Thanks, the only question I have now is whether or not the assassin will be revealed when he places a shroud without the feat Hidden Insight. As you said, it's not an attack so it should not break hidden, but if that's the case, what's the purpose of the feat?